# JavaScript/JQuery function to get the ORIGINAL height/width of an HTML element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When I use JQuery to try and get the height/width in pixels of an element, it gives me a decimal. For instance, calling `$("#someDiv").height()` returns something like `599.91239131923` if I have `#someDiv {height: 600px;}`. I'm wondering if there's some function where I could actually return the number `600`, corresponding to the number I set the `height` to be on page load. I need that number as a constant that I use elsewhere in my web app.

Comment: @JoshCrozier That's not safe.

Comment: Can you recreate this in a demo? Like [said in the query docu](http://api.jquery.com/height/) `The numbers returned by dimensions-related APIs, including .height(), may be fractional in some cases. Code should not assume it is an integer.` [But this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zmv1fcog/) is not showing the behaviour your describe. In this case `.height()` is rounding.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using:

```
$(element).css("height")
```